# how to extract text from table with same class name using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have tried to extract from the table with same class name but its getting messed the table.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as extractor
import requests
from dateutil import parser
import numpy as np

for page in range(1, 354):
    ba="https://www.airlinequality.com/airline-reviews/british-airways/page/"+str(page)
    Headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    response=requests.get(ba, headers=Headers)
    soup=extractor(response.content, "html.parser")
    for Reviewer in soup.findAll("article", itemprop="review"):
        type_of_traveller=Reviewer.find("tr", class_="review-rating-header type_of_traveller")
```

print(type_of_traveller)

When i try to print the above code i am getting a all the cell as None.

```
array([None, None, None, ..., None, None, None], dtype=object)
```

Expected Output

```
Type of Traveller
Couple leisure
Family leisure
Solo leisure
.
.
.
```

Does anyone know how to solve it.

Comment: There are 353 pages where i have to extract the text.and there are not only 4 types of travellers its just an example.

Answer (score 0):

> ```py
>         type_of_traveller=Reviewer.find("tr", class_="review-rating-header type_of_traveller")
> ```

There are no `tr` tags with that class on that page - you probably want the **`td`** tags with that class.

[image: td not tr]

---

Just change the line to

```py
        type_of_traveller=Reviewer.find("td", class_="review-rating-header type_of_traveller")
```

and it should be fine after that.